# Typescript Conditional Object Keys: Prop A exists Prob B must exist

Tags: typescript

### Background

I want to conditionally type keys in an object based on the existence of another key in that object.

### Problem

I have an object that has some required keys and some optional. I do not know how to make it so one of the optional keys is contingent upon the other optional key being present. For instance,

```js
interface User { 
  username: string;
  id: string;
  member?: boolean; 
  memberStatus?: string;
}
```

Now, let's say I have a list of users that I am mapping through and I want to show a button if the user is a `member` and make that button a specific color based on `memberStatus`.

```js
return users.map(user => (
  if(user.member) { 
    //memberStatus here will cause an error because it maybe a string or undefined
    <button className={memberStatus === 'active' ? 'green' : 'yellow'}>Member Button</button>
  }
  return (
    <p>{user.username} is a user</p>
  )
))
```

#### What I Tried

I looked up extending interfaces and conditional typing. However, extending a Member interface from the User interface but that still leaves me with optional keys.

#### Question

Is it possible to create an interface like so

```js
interface User { 
 username: string;
 id: string;
 member?: string;
 memberStatus: string; 
}

type UserOrMember = User.member ? User : Omit<User, 'memberStatus'>

apiUsers: UserOrMember = [...users]
```

Again, the goal is that `memberStatus` is only required if `member` is not `undefined`.

Is there anything I am missing with extending interfaces or generics that could be helpful?

Comment: There are probably other solutions, but why would you not have `memberStatus` only?

Comment: Would I not run into the same issue with TS saying `memberStatus` maybe a `string | undefined`? @ritaj What you are saying does make sense though not sure how that removes the TS issue.

Comment: I don't understand why "`memberStatus here will cause an error because it maybe a string or undefined`".  You can certainly compare `string | undefined` to a `string` with `===`.  What error would you see?

Comment: I guess I am thinking since I would have to access it like `user.memberStatus` which may not be defined.

Comment: You will just have `if(user.memberStatus) { // Here TS knows it's not undefined, so you can use it } `

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Tagged union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#tagged-union-types):

```js
// declare types
interface BaseUser {
  username: string;
  id: string;
  member?: boolean;
}

interface User extends BaseUser {
  member?: false;
}

interface Member extends BaseUser {
  member: true;
  memberStatus: string;
}

type UserOrMember = User | Member;

// usage in component
declare const user: UserOrMember
console.log(user.member ? user.memberStatus : user.username)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBOlQBcCeAHSBnAsAFACWAdqpIgGbzQoBC8OkAqk4qAN6GigCubJeAFtIALlA5UiUgHMA3N1BFw4ydJLzFIoQCMKAfnE6A9sdiR4JBQQC+hQqXJUaKVhVCQAHuRLgcoBiY3di4CHm09RENQalgmazsCBzIKalpQAFlIXXcvHz8AxhY2Ti1syPEpXkhrcPKKAGVUeFR+VSlZBPsCDGxQYIB5RCyc9gBefpKAH0z6xGtCED4ceBkUUlBoYyFMYxJIMkIoOCQULZJJZYpxQeG5wnOcM0gAOlhjGQAKfgoXiPd9FdEH85k0WvxQOIfsDoYIRABKQhAA)

Comment: This seems cool. Would I have to type `memberStatus` as a union with `never`? So if `member` is `false`, would that `console.log` through an error on memberStatus? I guess I can try out. Thanks for the link